# Reasoning about function statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function f() {
  function Ctor() {}
  return { instance: new Ctor(), referenceToCtor: Ctor };
}

var a = f();
var b = f();

a.instance instanceof a.referenceToCtor; // true
b.instance instanceof a.referenceToCtor; // false
```

What does this tell us about the meaning of `instanceof` and function statements?

Does this mean that each time `f` is invoked a completely new Function-object named `Ctor` is instantiated and hence `instanceof` returns `false`.

Is this similar to the problems of `instanceof Array` and multiple windows?

Comment: Put `function Ctor() {}` outside of `function f()`, and run those same tests again …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that each time `f` is invoked a completely new Function-object named `Ctor` is instantiated and hence `instanceof` returns `false`.

Yes.

> Is this similar to the problems of `instanceof Array` and multiple windows?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

That a function declaration creates a variable in a given scope, and you get a new function and new scope each time the outer function is run.

Yes and Yes.

Comment: Is there a semantic difference between the `[[Scope]]` object on the `LexicalEnvironment` and the static lexical scope? If so, does that mean it is more correct to say you get a new `[[Scope]]` object each time the outer function is run?